# Parse JSON Object - Object not found

Tags: json

I am new to JSON and trying to implement some examples of how to parse a json response but unable to get it right.

I have the response and use the following java code:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;


BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((connection.getInputStream())));
final JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(br.readLine());
```

if i print the `JSONObject` i get:

> {"xml-fragment":{"workItems":[{"id":{"@id":"251","@version":"1"},"visible":true,"state":"OPENED","header":{"@priority":"50","flags":{"scheduleStatus":"DURING"},"@startDate":"2013-10-15T12:30:57.493Z","description":"UserReconcile","@distributionStrategy":"OFFER","name":"UserReconcile","itemContext":{"appName":"NpdaProcess","appInstance":"pvm:0a12iq","activityName":"UserReconcile","appID":"*-hYCETV8EeOr4-yR8gXd7g","activityID":"pvm:001im4"}}},{"id":{"@id":"252","@version":"0"},"visible":true,"state":"OFFERED","header":{"@priority":"50","flags":{"scheduleStatus":"DURING"},"@startDate":"2013-10-15T12:31:15.263Z","description":"UserReconcile","@distributionStrategy":"OFFER","name":"UserReconcile","itemContext":{"appName":"NpdaProcess","appInstance":"pvm:0a12ir","activityName":"UserReconcile","appID":"*-hYCETV8EeOr4-yR8gXd7g","activityID":"pvm:001imh"}}}],"totalItems":2,"endPosition":1,"startPosition":0}}

Then i try:
`final JSONArray geodata = obj.getJSONArray("workItems");` but it fails with

```
JSONObject["workItems"] not found.
```

From what i understand in the json doc is that workItems should be the array name or is that wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your workitems array is still within your xml-fragment.
try

```
final JSONArray geodata = obj.getJSONObject("xml-fragment").getJSONArray("workItems");
```

Comment: Thanks it worked.  What is confusing though is that i have a json obj, and then i have to say obj.getJSONObject(....).  I'll keep practicing, get the hang of json :)